# google forms multiple choice grid: validate

Tags: validation, google-forms

I am trying to put together a multiple choice grid in a google form, which should have some logic in it.

The idea is that people can use the form to predict a starting line up from a football team. I want to keep the form as easy and small as possible, thus going for a multiple choice grid.

The design I had in mind to use is pretty simple:

[image: example of form]

The logic I need is:

- you can and must put only 1 player on goal
- the total number of players selected should be 11
- if you reach the 11 selection, you shouldn't be able to select any more players
- if you have selected 1 player on goal, you shouldn't be able to select any more players on goal

Ideally: the check should be dynamic, while you are filling in the form. As soon as you reach the 11th name, you shouldn't be able to continue selecting options.

I have already tried tinkering with some add-ons for google forms, but they all struggle with the multiple choice grid.

Does any one have any advice how and if I can even achieve this with google forms or maybe it's wiser to move on to another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what you want (a different number of selections for each column) you'd need to have them as separate questions. I haven't used a survey platform that would do what you want the way you've been thinking about it.

So, you'd have a question asking who they want the goalie to be. Then you'd have another question where you ask which 10 other players they'd select for the other positions. To get fancy, you'd make a separate question for each person that's selected for goalie, that would ask about the other positions, leaving out who the goalie.

Comment: that gives me a whole new problem: you can't get over 9 options with a select grid. I think I need to hope that people don't start doubleselecting names (or at least not many people do that) :) Google forms is a bit too static for my wishlist I guess

Comment: i adjusted the complete layout, based also on your advice :) I first ask which tactic one wants to follow and let the form jump to a new section. Here the goalie is in a seperate question. The problem of being able to put the same player twice in the line-up still remains, but i'm putting my money for now on that not many people will do that, so the overall votes will not be affected that much by this 'feature'. The only other solution is to work out a form on my own with 'on select' options in it.